# can we use jpa without hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I am new to JPA.

As per my understanding, JPA is specification and Hibernate implements JPA and provide add on features along with JPA methods.

But I was going through JPA tutorials, where using `EntityManager` object we can perform CRUD on data, without using Hibernate libraries!

So can anyone please let me know

1. Can I use JPA alone using `EntityManager` methods, not using Hibernate?

Please mention some useful link or example.

Much appreciate response.
Thanks.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You are right JPA is a specification. Hibernate, and EclipseLink are a couple of its implementations.

You have to specify the persistence provider(Hibernate, EclipseLink) in order to use the JPA implementation. The persistence providers have the implementation classes for JPA specifications.

Comment: Thanks for reply...   actually i want to know what exactly is entityManager used for in jpa ?   i am referring to this link      <link> http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbqw.html#bnbqx </link>  where without using any hibernate it is performing db operations ...

Comment: if you are familiar with hibernate. Entitymanager is just like hibernate session. As per the EntityManager definition "The EntityManager API is used to create and remove persistent entity instances, to find entities by their primary key, and to query over entities." just like hibernate session or jdbc connection.

Comment: ok ... got it ... EntityManager belongs to Hibernate-jpa-api jar...    and hibernate session belongs to Hibernate specific jar.              so if we want to use jpa then we should only use methods which are defined in hibernate-jpa-api instead of hibernate specific to get benefit of jpa ... am I correct ?

Comment: JPA is a specifications and not implementation (you can think of JDBC sepciciations in java jre java.sql packages it contains all interfaces and no actual implementation). There are different JPA implementations available e.g. Hibernate, EclipseLink etc. (similar to what implementation in odbc.jar for oracle and other DB specific driver jar files). In order to use JPA you need to chose some implementation.  In a layman's term if you want to use JPA without hibernate system may not be aware which implementation class it will use for JPA interface EntityManager.

Comment: Can some one please tell me in single word "yes" or "no". can i use jpa alone without any frameworks like hibernate, eclipse link etc?

Comment: @raj240: NO. When you use Spring Data, by default Hibernate jar is added thanks to Springboots's opinionated nature. Of course, you are free to use other implementations of JPA, like EclipseLink by just altering the configuration. Please refer to my answer below.

Answer (score 11):

Though this thread is pretty old, I felt it is worth breaking things down.

**JPA:** It Is just a specification. In simpler words. Set of interfaces.

**Hibernate, Eclipse Link, Apache OpenJPA:** A few of the many implementations of JPA. In addition to providing the basic implementations for the JPA specifications, Hibernate and other implementations provide their additional functionalities. You can choose based on your need

**Spring Data:**

- It provides additional abstraction.
- When you use Hibernate/Eclipse Link you still have to write some boilerplate code. By using Spring JPA you can avoid that.
- The most important thing to note is Spring data uses Hibernate by Default due to Springboot's Opinionated nature. You can change the default behavior if you would like.
- When you run the following command in a Springboot project that uses Spring JPA(with default configuration), you will see Hibernate jars being used.

> Maven: `mvn dependency:tree`
>
> Gradle: `gradle dependencies`

Answer (score 6):

You can't just use JPA, cause it is an API =), but there are plenty JPA implementations:

1. [EclipseLink](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/)
2. [ObjectDB](http://www.objectdb.com/)

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to use Hibernate (or any other JPA provider), then you must implement your own provider, by giving an implementation for the javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider interface.
The question, is, why do you need re-invent the wheel ? 
If you don't like Hibernate, you can use one of the so many other JPA-Providers to choose from

Comment: in my case I don't want to use JPA because I have a table in legacy that don't have an ID . so is there any way to CRUD this table using JPA .

Comment: you can use a tool like Mybatis, and write your own queries

Answer (score 4):

JPA can be used without a JPA provider aka Hibernate, EclipseLink and so on only if the application server has already a JPA implementation. Most likely on the tutorials you have seen demos that were perfomed on such an application server.

Answer (score 2):

You can use JPA alone without using Hibernate and Before should know about major points in between Hibernate vs JPA as given below.

Hibernate

1. Hibernate is a ORM Framework which is support complete ORM and also use JPA features.
2. Second level Cache is available so Performance is very good
3. Its support .Net using NHibernate tool
4. Its generate HQL(Hibernate Query Language)

JPA

1. JPA is part of EJB specification which is released in J2EE 1.5 and this will use for java as well as J2EE
2. Second Level Cache is not available so Performance is not good.
3. Its not support to .Net
4. Its generate JPQL(Java Persistence Query Language)
5. Top of any persistence provider like Hibernate we can use JPA.

Comment: I got the differences. But still, I am not able to understand, how can we use JPA alone? since its an API only.

Comment: you can't use it alone, I guess the "alone" might be just by specifying the reference implementation, which is EclipseLink, but that's not "alone", it's just probably the default implementation if you follow a standardized tutorial.

Comment: "Hibernate performance is very good" ???  Maybe until you hit your head against the N+1 problem.  You want to join to another table?  Hibernate does one select for each linked entity.

Answer (score 2):

you can't use JPA on its own. JPA is a specification, which defines an API for object-relational mappings and for managing persistent objects and you need a JPA provider to implement it, like Hibernate, EclipseLink.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot perform CRUD operations with JPA alone. As JPA is just a specification, you need the implementation to perform database operations. The implementations are provided by Hibernate, EclipseLink, Ibatis, etc.